# Is it ideally correct to benchmark neo4j as graph processing platform?

Tags: graphs, neo4j

I would like to know if neo4j can be considered a graph processing platform, even though i know that:

neo4j: is a graph database management system developed by Neo Technology, Inc. Described by its developers as an ACID-compliant transactional database with native graph storage and processing.

graph processing platform: is a platform used for processing graphs, by applying global algorithms towards large graphs (used more in OLAP scenario).

Based on this paper http://www.ds.ewi.tudelft.nl/~iosup/perf-eval-graph-proc14ipdps.pdf, neo4j is benchmarked as a processing platform.

So my question is, if its correct to put neo4j in the group of processing platform like pregel and giraph.

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why? And since its incorrect, why there is a paper published with neo4j considered as graph processing platform?

Comment: Because even the [neo4j staff](http://neo4j.com/blog/graph-processing-v-graph-databases-jim-webber/) do not make this claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

As Emre has rightly pointed out, the Chief Scientist of the company himself has written a blog post claiming the same.

However, Neo4j does a lot of computations which graph processing tools can do. In fact, it does graph traversals much faster than giraph, due to the Hadoop overhead and also as it stores the adjacent nodes in a doubly linked list.

So, it's not rare to confuse Neo4j with a graph processing platform (thus the claim in the paper) due to it's overlap with the features of a processing platform like Pregel and Giraph.